# How do I set cascade delete for one collection, not the other in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the class Campaign that has two 1:many collections:

```
public class Campaign
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }

    // more properties
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    // Events have an "owner" that is one of three objects. This is one of them.
    public Campaign? Campaign { get; set; }

    // more properties
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }

    // more properties
}
```

When I delete a campaign object, I want to delete all of the Event objects in its collection. But not delete the User/Followers collection object. At present neither is deleted.

I thought when there's a relationship like this it does delete the children and figured my problem was having it not delete user/followers. But it's the reverse.

So, how do I tell it to cascade delete the Events list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely would behave as you expect if Event.Campaign was non-null-able but this comment (`// Events have an "owner" that is one of three objects. This is one of them.`) leads me to believe you have other possible FKs to relate an event to another entity. In this case an automatic cascade delete would not be available, you will need to do it manually or possibly via client-side cascade. If an Event might be assigned to a Campaign OR Course OR SomethingElse based on one of these FKs being populated, as far as the table and relationships are concerned, EF won't know that just because an Event might be associated to a Campaign, that it won't be associated to another entity type at the same time. This is an implied rule, not enforceable in the schema so EF won't do it automatically or be able to rely on a DB provided cascade.

You may be able to get the behaviour by configuring the relationship to cascade delete on the client:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Campaign>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Events)
    .WithOne(x => x.Campaign)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
```

This would require you to eager-load the related events prior to deleting the campaign:

```
var campaignToDelete = _context.Campaigns
    .Include(x => x.Events)
    .Single(x => x.Id == campaignIdToDelete);
_context.Events.Remove(campaignToDelete);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

barring that, you'd need to remove the events explicitly:

```
var campaignToDelete = _context.Campaigns
    .Include(x => x.Events)
    .Single(x => x.Id == campaignIdToDelete);

foreach(var event in campaignToDelete.Events)
    _context.Events.Remove(event);
_context.Campaigns.Remove(CampaignToDelete);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Your fluent suggestion worked - even without the eager loading! Also, I very much appreciate your answers - you're helping me learn the little details of EF a lot.

Comment: Good to hear!  Be cautious with the `ClientCascade` and eager loading as it should work  as expected so long as all of the related Events happen to be tracked due to the events being previously loaded within the DbContext's lifetime. But if you were to load a Campaign where one or more events *weren't* already tracked without eager loading them, it would almost certainly leave orphans/fail.